# GroupLayout not functioning as expected

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jcomponent, grouplayout

I am trying to create a minesweeper type game and have designed the interface around a GridLayout at the top, and a JPanel at the bottom. I am having problems arranging the JComponents on the info panel at the bottom. I am using a GroupLayout to arrange the items in the info panel.

Below is a basic drawing of how it should appear :

[image: Plan]

And here is the actual result :

[image: Result]

I do not understand why the bottom most JLabels (Big ones which are the playerXTurnIndicator labels) do not show up at all. Surely when they are added to the group with no text by default they take the size of the area that the horizontal or vertical layout dictates?

```
private void createComponents() {     
    playerOneNameLabel = new JLabel("Name : ");
    playerTwoNameLabel = new JLabel("Name : ");
    playerOneScoreLabel = new JLabel("Score : ");
    playerTwoScoreLabel = new JLabel("Score : ");

    playerOneNameDataLabel = new JLabel("");
    playerTwoNameDataLabel = new JLabel("");
    playerOneScoreDataLabel = new JLabel("0");
    playerTwoScoreDataLabel = new JLabel("0");

    playerOneTurnIndicatorLabel = new JLabel();
    playerOneTurnIndicatorLabel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    playerOneTurnIndicatorLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));

    playerTwoTurnIndicatorLabel = new JLabel();
    playerTwoTurnIndicatorLabel.setBackground(Color.RED);
    playerTwoTurnIndicatorLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));

    infoMinesRemainingLabel = new JLabel("Mines Remaining : ");
    infoMinesRemainingData = new JLabel("0");

    infoTileCoordLabel = new JLabel("Tile : ");
    infoTileCoordDataLabel = new JLabel("0, 0");

    playerOneBombButton = new JButton("Bomb");
    playerTwoBombButton = new JButton("Bomb");

    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);

    layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
    layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(
                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(
                            layout.createParallelGroup()
                                .addGroup(
                                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(playerOneNameLabel)
                                        .addComponent(playerOneNameDataLabel))
                                .addGroup(
                                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(playerOneScoreLabel)
                                        .addComponent(playerOneScoreDataLabel))
                                .addComponent(playerOneTurnIndicatorLabel))
                        .addComponent(playerOneBombButton))
                .addGap(10)
                .addGroup(
                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(
                            layout.createParallelGroup()
                                .addComponent(infoMinesRemainingLabel)
                                .addComponent(infoTileCoordLabel))
                        .addGroup(
                            layout.createParallelGroup()
                                .addComponent(infoMinesRemainingData)
                                .addComponent(infoTileCoordDataLabel)))
                .addGap(10)
                .addGroup(
                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(playerTwoBombButton)
                        .addGroup(
                            layout.createParallelGroup()
                                .addGroup(
                                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(playerTwoNameLabel)
                                        .addComponent(playerTwoNameDataLabel))
                                .addGroup(
                                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(playerTwoScoreLabel)
                                        .addComponent(playerTwoScoreDataLabel))
                                .addComponent(playerTwoTurnIndicatorLabel))));

    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addGroup(
                    layout.createParallelGroup()
                        .addGroup(
                            layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(
                                    layout.createParallelGroup()
                                        .addComponent(playerOneNameLabel)
                                        .addComponent(playerOneNameDataLabel))
                                .addGroup(
                                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(
                                            layout.createParallelGroup()
                                                .addComponent(playerOneScoreLabel)
                                                .addComponent(playerOneScoreDataLabel)))
                                .addComponent(playerOneTurnIndicatorLabel))
                        .addComponent(playerOneBombButton)
                    )
                .addGap(50)
                .addGroup(
                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(
                            layout.createParallelGroup()
                                .addComponent(infoMinesRemainingLabel)
                                .addComponent(infoMinesRemainingData))
                        .addGroup(
                            layout.createParallelGroup()
                                .addComponent(infoTileCoordLabel)
                                .addComponent(infoTileCoordDataLabel)))
                .addGap(50)
                .addGroup(
                    layout.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(playerTwoBombButton)
                        .addGroup(
                            layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(
                                    layout.createParallelGroup()
                                        .addComponent(playerTwoNameLabel)
                                        .addComponent(playerTwoNameDataLabel))
                                .addGroup(
                                    layout.createParallelGroup()
                                        .addComponent(playerTwoScoreLabel)
                                        .addComponent(playerTwoScoreDataLabel))
                                .addComponent(playerTwoTurnIndicatorLabel))));

    this.setLayout(layout);
}
```

Regards,

Jamie

Comment: hmmm I'd be to use GridBagLayout for JPanel with JLabel and JButton

Comment: I admit, there are most likely going to be other ways of doing this however I felt that GroupLayout was the most flexible (or at least offered the most flexibility) due to the potential GridLayout above being set to different sizes. I am just unsure how to fit in constraints to align different groups and how to make the JLabels, which will have their backgrounds set to a different colour depending on who's turn it is, a size that makes them show up. Even setting their size seems to have no effect.

Comment: @Jamie If you use LayoutManager's (which you should always do!), setting size, bounds or location makes absolutely no sense and will be totally useless.

Answer (score 1):

The JLabels are shown (therefore the free space at the bottom), but have no color. Use JPanels instead (background only works with opaque components, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29).

Comment: Surely if I setOpaque() to both JLabels then that would mean that there would be one big red rectangle and one big green rectangle?

Comment: I think backgrounds of JLabels are only shown behind text: no text > no background. Use JPanel - it works. If you need the label, wrap it in the panel.

Comment: Brilliant, that gets the blocks up. I have added a few gaps to the horizontal layout and over a certain size it allows the layout to exceed the stated limit on the infoPanel. I thought it would stop when it tried to draw over the maximum size of the panel?

Comment: Maybe GroupLayout ignores the values of its container? But you can set maximum values for the components inside the layout with *.addComponent(Component component, int min, int pref, int max)* [see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html for more information]. I hope this is useful for you.